# Issue when updating values in plist containing dictionary of arrays

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a plist which has a dictionary of arrays. I'm new to swift and struggling to simply update a value in my plist.
Here is a sample plist file I'm dealing with in my App:

```
<dict>
    <key>SomeKey1</key>
    <array>
        <string>100</string>
        <string>Company1</string>
    </array>
    <key>SomeKey2</key>
    <array>
        <string>500</string>
        <string>Company2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

In my app, I display the above plist values in a table view. When user selects a row in the table, it populates 2 text fields (Number and Company) with the values.This works fine. I want to update the values in my textfields, click a save button and then reload the table data. 
The plist file is copied to Documents folder so that it's writable (as per http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/). 
The following piece of code updates the values, but deletes the "SomeKey1" and I can't figure out why it would do that. Am I missing something?

```
    let path = pathToDocsFolder()
    var myKey="SomeKey2" //Has the value "SomeKey1" or "SomeKey2"
    var valArray=[textfieldNumber.text, textfieldCompany.text]
    var thisdict: NSMutableDictionary = ["XInitializerItem": "DoNotEverChangeMe"]
    thisdict.setObject(valArray, forKey: myKey)
    thisdict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myKey="SomeKey2" //Has the value "SomeKey1" or "SomeKey2"
var valArray=[textfieldNumber.text, textfieldCompany.text]

let path = pathToDocsFolder()
let plistDict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
plistDict.setObject(valArray, forKey: myKey)
plistDict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
```

Comment: Ahh. How did I miss that.